# Changing visibility of stacked images using JavaScript onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, visibility

I am trying to cycle through images each time I press a button on the page. I have made a function that seems like it should change the visibility of the images, but it does not. What do I need to do to my script to change the visibility and switch to a new image each time the button is pressed?

My current code:

```js
function switcher() {

    var x = document.images[0].style;
    var y = document.images[1].style;
    var z = document.images[2].style;

    while (x.visibility == "visible") {
        x.visibility = "hidden";
        y.visibility = "visible";
        z.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    while (y.visibility == "visible") {
        x.visibility = "hidden";
        y.visibility = "hidden";
        z.visibility = "visible";
    }
    while (z.visibility == "visible") {
        x.visibility = "visible";
        y.visibility = "hidden";
        z.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

```css
.sawpic {position: absolute; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; visibility: visible;}
            .plierspic {position: absolute; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; visibility: hidden;}
            .planerpic {position: absolute; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; visibility: hidden;}
            .picContainer {text-align: center; clear: left;}
            .bcontain {margin-top: 300px; margin-bottom: 100px;}
            button {display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
```

```html
<h1>Lab 5, part 1</h1>
<div class="picContainer">
    <img class= "sawpic" id="sawpic" src = "https://placeimg.com/364/248/nature" alt ="picture of saw"/>
    <img class= "plierspic" id="plierspic" src = "https://placeimg.com/364/248/people" alt ="picture of pliers"/>
    <img class= "planerpic" id="planerpic" src = "https://placeimg.com/364/248/tech" alt ="picture of planer"/>
<br />
<div class="bcontain">
    <button type="button" onclick= "switcher()">Next</button>
</div>
</div>
<h3>Links</h3>
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use the `while` loop; you need to check the `visibility` using the `if` 
 / `else if` / `else` condition. Also, you need to call the `switcher` function right away, so that the other two images are hidden, on page load.

Try the following:

```js
switcher();
function switcher() {

    var x = document.getElementById("sawpic");
    var y = document.getElementById("plierspic");
    var z = document.getElementById("planerpic");

    if(x.style.visibility == "visible") {
        x.style.visibility = "hidden";
        y.style.visibility = "visible";
        z.style.visibility = "hidden";
        console.log("Showing Y");
    } else if(y.style.visibility == "visible") {
        x.style.visibility = "hidden";
        y.style.visibility = "hidden";
        z.style.visibility = "visible";
        console.log("Showing Z");
    } else if(z.style.visibility == "visible") {
        x.style.visibility = "visible";
        y.style.visibility = "hidden";
        z.style.visibility = "hidden";
        console.log("Showing X");
    } else {
        x.style.visibility = "visible";
        y.style.visibility = "hidden";
        z.style.visibility = "hidden";
        console.log("Showing X, by default");
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Lab 5, part 1</h1>
<div class="picContainer">
    <img class= "sawpic" id="sawpic" src = "https://placeimg.com/364/248/nature" alt ="picture of saw"/>
    <img class= "plierspic" id="plierspic" src = "https://placeimg.com/364/248/people" alt ="picture of pliers"/>
    <img class= "planerpic" id="planerpic" src = "https://placeimg.com/364/248/tech" alt ="picture of planer"/>
</div>
<div class="bcontain">
    <button type="button" onclick= "switcher()">Next</button>
</div>
<h3>Links</h3>
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the code like this and you can easily scale to any number of image. It also better to use an `.active` class so you can change the CSS behavior without changing the JS.

```js
var allImg=document.querySelectorAll('.picContainer img');
var l = allImg.length;
var current = 0;

function switcher() {
   allImg[current].classList.remove('active');
   current++;
   if(current == l)
      current=0;
   allImg[current].classList.add('active');
   
}
```

```css
img {
  display: none;
}
img.active {
  display:block;
}

.picContainer {
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
}


button {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>Lab 5, part 1</h1>
<div class="picContainer">
  <img class="active" id="sawpic" src="https://placeimg.com/364/248/nature" alt="picture of saw" >
  <img  id="plierspic" src="https://placeimg.com/364/248/people" alt="picture of pliers" >
  <img  id="planerpic" src="https://placeimg.com/364/248/tech" alt="picture of planer" >
  <br >
  <div class="bcontain">
    <button type="button" onclick="switcher()">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This may work, but its completely different code. I'm trying to figure out why my function is not working the way it is intended.

Comment: @SavageCoder it's a complete different and **better** code ... i know you are looking for why your code is not working and you had the answer in the comment but even if you fix it, it remain a bad code ... so i tried to understand your logic and provided a better and easy to understand code. We should not only fix the code if we can also fix the logic behind ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change your `function` logic from `while` to `if`. Use the next one:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>l5p1</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .sawpic {position: absolute; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block;}
            .plierspic {position: absolute; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: none;}
            .planerpic {position: absolute; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: none;}
            .picContainer {text-align: center; clear: left;}
            .bcontain {margin-top: 300px; margin-bottom: 100px;}
            button {display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function switcher() {

                var x = document.images[0];
                var y = document.images[1];
                var z = document.images[2];

                var xComputedStyle = getComputedStyle(x);
                var yComputedStyle = getComputedStyle(y);
                var zComputedStyle = getComputedStyle(z);

              console.log(document.images[0], xComputedStyle.display);
               

                if (xComputedStyle.display == 'block') {
                    x.style.display = 'none';
                    y.style.display = 'block';
                    z.style.display = 'none';
                }
                else if (yComputedStyle.display == 'block') {
                    x.style.display = 'none';
                    y.style.display = 'none';
                    z.style.display = 'block';
                }
                else if (zComputedStyle.display == 'block') {
                    x.style.display = 'block';
                    y.style.display = 'none';
                    z.style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        </script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Lab 5, part 1</h1>
        <div class="picContainer">
            <img class= "sawpic" id="sawpic" src = "https://placeimg.com/364/248/nature" alt ="picture of saw"/>
            <img class= "plierspic" id="plierspic" src = "https://placeimg.com/364/248/people" alt ="picture of pliers"/>
            <img class= "planerpic" id="planerpic" src = "https://placeimg.com/364/248/tech" alt ="picture of planer"/>
        <br />
        <div class="bcontain">
            <button type="button" onclick= "switcher()">Next</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        <h3>Links</h3>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried using if else, but the picture still does not change

Comment: Try the next one. I have update the code. Just run for test. @SavageCoder

Answer (score 0):

Use DOM selection methods instead. Also, better not to inline Javascript.

```js
const styles = [...document.querySelectorAll('.picContainer > img')]
  .map(img => img.style);

document.querySelector('.bcontain > button').addEventListener('click', switcher);
function switcher() {
  const foundIndex = styles.findIndex(style => style.visibility === 'visible');
  styles.forEach(style => style.visibility = 'hidden');
  styles[((foundIndex + 1) || 1) % styles.length]
    .visibility = 'visible';
}
```

```css
.sawpic {position: absolute; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; visibility: visible;}
.plierspic {position: absolute; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; visibility: hidden;}
.planerpic {position: absolute; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; visibility: hidden;}
.picContainer {text-align: center; clear: left;}
.bcontain {margin-top: 300px; margin-bottom: 100px;}
button {display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>l5p1</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Lab 5, part 1</h1>
        <div class="picContainer">
            <img class= "sawpic" id="sawpic" src = "https://placeimg.com/364/248/nature" alt ="picture of saw"/>
            <img class= "plierspic" id="plierspic" src = "https://placeimg.com/364/248/people" alt ="picture of pliers"/>
            <img class= "planerpic" id="planerpic" src = "https://placeimg.com/364/248/tech" alt ="picture of planer"/>
        <br />
        <div class="bcontain">
            <button type="button">Next</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        <h3>Links</h3>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `switcher` function resets itself, because all the `while` conditions will be true and the end-state will be the same as the start-state.

Your current function attempts to handle a situation with three images. But you probably want to be able to handle any number of images. Try using the following sample code:

```
var currentVisibleIndex = -1;

function switcher() {
    var maxIndex = document.images.length - 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < maxIndex; i++)
        document.images[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }

    if(currentVisibleIndex < maxIndex) {
        currentVisibleIndex++;
    } else {
        currentVisibleIndex = 0;
    }

    document.images[currentVisibleIndex].style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

The `for` loop hides all the images. The `currentVisibleIndex` variable placed outside of the switcher function is maintained even when the `switcher` function isn't executing, due to the JavaScript function scope. The `if` and `else` statement make sure the index is set to a value that is not going outside of the number of images you have. Finally the last line sets the image to be visible.